# Where could I find the log configuration file in Weblogic server?

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic

We could modify this file to change the log generation way. For example, We
could change the log rolling way, by hour or by day; and show different log types: info,error and etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to Weblogic standard log files or log4j config for your application?

Comment: Yes, It is. In jboss server, we could find a file named as jboss-log4j.xml. What I want to find in Weblogic server is like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find a file named as config.xml.

It has an item to config log.

Like:

```
<log>
  <file-name>logs/examplesServer.log</file-name>
  <rotation-type>byTime</rotation-type>
  <number-of-files-limited>true</number-of-files-limited>
  <file-time-span>24</file-time-span>
  <rotation-time>00:00</rotation-time>
  <rotate-log-on-startup>true</rotate-log-on-startup>
  <logger-severity>Info</logger-severity>
  <log-file-severity>Debug</log-file-severity>
  <stdout-severity>Notice</stdout-severity>
  <domain-log-broadcast-severity>Notice</domain-log-broadcast-severity>
  <memory-buffer-severity>Trace</memory-buffer-severity>
  <log4j-logging-enabled>false</log4j-logging-enabled>
  <redirect-stdout-to-server-log-enabled>false</redirect-stdout-to-server-log-enabled>
  <domain-log-broadcaster-buffer-size>1</domain-log-broadcaster-buffer-size>
</log>
```

Thanks,
Joseph